# Is it possible to read discord messages from a group where you aren't an admin? (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Is it possible to read discord messages from a group where you aren't an admin in python?
I've seen that discord.py is the most used library for discord related stuff but I only can find how to create a bot. I just want to read messages from a specific text channel of a group.

Is this possible? 
Or do I need to use a web scraper?

Comment: just create a bot, but on the client.run, give the bot your own token so it logs in as you, it doesnt need to be a seperate user, you are just giving the code your token to login as you and automate your actions

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Can you give me some example code of what you exactly mean? I'm new to discord.py.

Comment: Sorry i take it back you cannot have a bot run a user account its against the TOS so indeed you would need to createa a bot account and have that group allow it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bot accounts cannot be added to group DMs. The (still unfulfilled) feature request can be found [here](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360032358092).

Self-botting, meaning running code from your own Discord account is against the Discord TOS and might get you banned. Don't do it.

As those are the only two options there is currently no way to read Group DMs programmatically.